# xcode Removing Some Subviews from view

Tags: xcode, subviews

Greetings all,

I am a noob and I have been trying to work through this for a few days.

I am adding images to a view via UItouch. The view contains a background on top of which the new images are add. How do I clear the images I am adding from the subview, without getting rid of the UIImage that is the background. Any assistance is greatly appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

here is the code:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *) event { 
NSUInteger numTaps = [[touches anyObject] tapCount];

if (numTaps==2) {
    imageCounter.text =@"two taps registered";      

//__ remove images  
    UIView* subview;
    while ((subview = [[self.view subviews] lastObject]) != nil)
        [subview removeFromSuperview];

    return;

}else {

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    CGRect myImageRect = CGRectMake((touchPoint.x -40), (touchPoint.y -45), 80.0f, 90.0f); 
    UIImageView *myImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:myImageRect];

    [myImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pg6_dog_button.png"]];
     myImage.opaque = YES; // explicitly opaque for performance


    [self.view addSubview:myImage];
    [myImage release];

    [imagesArray addObject:myImage];

    NSNumber *arrayCount =[self.view.subviews count];
    viewArrayCount.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",arrayCount];
    imageCount=imageCount++;
    imageCounter.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",imageCount];

}
```

}

Answer (score 29):

What you need is a way of distinguishing the added `UIImageView` objects from the background `UIImageView`. There are two ways I can think of to do this.

**Approach 1: Assign added `UIImageView` objects a special tag value**

Each `UIView` object has a `tag` property which is simply an integer value that can be used to identify that view. You could set the tag value of each added view to 7 like this:

```
myImage.tag = 7;
```

Then, to remove the added views, you could step through all of the subviews and only remove the ones with a tag value of 7:

```
for (UIView *subview in [self.view subviews]) {
    if (subview.tag == 7) {
        [subview removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

**Approach 2: Remember the background view**

Another approach is to keep a reference to the background view so you can distinguish it from the added views. Make an `IBOutlet` for the background `UIImageView` and assign it the usual way in Interface Builder. Then, before removing a subview, just make sure it's not the background view.

```
for (UIView *subview in [self.view subviews]) {
    if (subview != self.backgroundImageView) {
        [subview removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

Comment: Answer 1 is generally correct but note that you could restrict the search using [UIView viewWithTag: 7] and not have to iterate through every single view. Of course, this might not save you anything, but it is a nice thing to know

Comment: Guys thanks so much for your input. I will try these out today. I did a long work around which was to add the background back after everything had been cleared. Not exactly elegant but it worked..

Comment: Your workaround is very clever, though it might not work so well when you need more control over your views. If you try using `viewWithTag:`, as suggested by @justin, keep in mind that it will only return the first view found with a matching tag. It's a very convenient method when there's only one such view. If you have lots of views with matching tags, you'll end up iterating to find them all. Extra tip: Views have a default tag value of zero, so avoid using zero as an identifying tag value.

Answer (score 0):

A more swiftly code for approach #1 in only one functional line of code :

```
self.view.subviews.filter({$0.tag == 7}).forEach({$0.removeFromSuperview()})
```