# uiview duplicated when switching view controller

Tags: ios, ipad, uiview, uiviewcontroller, isgl3d

I have 2 ViewControllers that I use App delegate to switch them according to user interaction.

in AppDelegate.m I have:

```
    - (void) switchViews
{
    if (_viewController.view.superview == nil) {
        [_window addSubview:_viewController.view];
        [_window bringSubviewToFront:_viewController.view];
        [viewController2.view removeFromSuperview];
    } else
    {
        [_window addSubview:_viewController2.view];
        [_window bringSubviewToFront:_viewController2.view];

        [_viewController.view removeFromSuperview];
    } 
}
```

_viewController is for main view and _viewController2 is for glview(I am using isgl3d). The switch works but everytime I switch back to glview, I see duplicated view on top, which I suspect even main view is duplicated too.

Any idea how can I remove the view entirely so that I don't have this issue? Thanks!

Comment: Try to remove the subviews in a loop: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4136925/1011125

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be adding and removing the views like this, just change which controller is the root view controller of the window. Doing that make the new controller's view a subview of the window, and removes the old controller's view.

```
if ([self.window.rootViewController isEqual: _viewController]) {
    self.window.rootViewController = viewController2;
}else{
    self.window.rootViewController = viewController;
```

Comment: Thanks! rdelmar. Your method works. But I have to find another way to addsubview. If I add both subview in applicationDidFinishLaunching, both view are running eventhough only a view is on screen.

Comment: @sooon, I don't understand your comment. What do you mean, "both views are running"?

Comment: Maybe my question is when should I instantiate the viewController2? What I currently do is I instantiate both VCs in AppDelegate's "applicationDidFinishLaunching".

Comment: @sooon, it depends on when you want it. There's no reason to instantiate it until you're ready to switch to it.

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to do this after watching Stanford Coding Together:IOS.

Some critical info of VC that I am not aware of:
Everytime VC is instantiate, `viewDidLoad` is called once to setup all the important stuff like outlets and such. Then `viewWillAppear` and `viewWillDisappear` will be called for in between view swapping. Because it is called just a moment before view is shown to user, all the geometry setting like view orientation and size is set here.

so what I do is:
I `addSubview` in `viewDidLoad`, the do all the running setup in `viewWillappear` and `viewWillDisappear`.

one more note: view will remain there as long as the app still running.

anyway Thanks rdelmar for helping.