# How can I remove or hide a sublayer?

Tags: objective-c, calayer

```
-(IBAction)displayinfo:(id)sender
{
    sublayer = [CALayer layer];

    if (appear == NO)
    {
        appear = YES;
        sublayer.contents=(id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"infoPalette.png"].CGImage;
        sublayer.frame= CGRectMake(300,200,350,250);
        [self.view.layer addSublayer:sublayer];
    }
    else
    {
        [sublayer removeFromSuperlayer];
    }
}
```

This allows the layer to appear but I can't remove it or hide it upon clicking the same button.

Comment: possible duplicate of [xcode Removing Some Subviews from view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4136733/xcode-removing-some-subviews-from-view)

Comment: This is a duplicate of thousands of questions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Replace your existing code with this one

```
-(IBAction)displayinfo:(id)sender
{

    if ( appear == NO)
    {
         sublayer = [CALayer layer];
         appear = YES;
         sublayer.contents=(id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"infoPalette.png"].CGImage;
         sublayer.frame= CGRectMake(300,200,350,250);
         [self.view.layer addSublayer:sublayer];
    }
    else
    {
        [sublayer removeFromSuperlayer];
    }
}
```

Comment: are you replace self.view with your UIImageview name because you want to remove UIImageview's sub view

Comment: ok ... where are you applying sublayer? To UIImageview or to UIView?

Comment: no i didn't replace anything just i copy paste of the code that you have been written it

Comment: ok ok i got it. I think there is no require to post same comment again and again

Comment: ya i know but i got a spelling error this why i repeat it again

Comment: @RolaMasrie ok let's check me

Comment: @RolaMasrie hi i got your solution

Comment: @RolaMasrie put sublayer = [CALayer layer]; inside your if condition from outside

Comment: @RolaMasrie are you got your answer?

Comment: @RolaMasrie ok thank you man... call me anytime whenever you want to help.. thank you again ...

Comment: @RolaMasrie oh... i'm really sorry... :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42466/discussion-between-pradhyuman-chavda-and-rola-masrie)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42632/discussion-between-pradhyuman-chavda-and-rola-masrie)

Answer (score 6):

In my case where I added multiple sublayers to my background imageView, I removed all of them using

```
 for (int i = 0 ; i < [self.backgroundImageView.layer.sublayers count]; i++ ) {
        [[self.backgroundImageView.layer.sublayers objectAtIndex:i] removeFromSuperlayer];
    }
```

Note: I also iterated like this

```
 for (CALayer *layer in self.backgroundImageView.layer.sublayers) {
      [layer removeFromSuperlayer];
 }
```

but this results in BadAccess, probably the reason that I added some CAGradientLayer to backgroundImageView.Layer. (it doesn't make much sense though).

Comment: This call is quicker and easier:    <br/>    `[image.layer.sublayers makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperlayer)];`

Answer (score 0):

You change the code to be

```
- (IBAction)displayinfo:(id)sender{
if (appear == NO){
    sublayer = [CALayer layer];
    appear = YES;
    sublayer.contents=(id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"infoPalette.png"].CGImage;
    sublayer.frame= CGRectMake(300,200,350,250);
    [self.view.layer addSublayer:sublayer];
}
else {
    [sublayer removeFromSuperlayer];
}}
```

**Sorry!, repeated solution**

Comment: Thanks hani your answer was so helpfull